# Create multimedia component using Tridion Web 8 core Service

Tags: web8, multimedia, component

The admin users are able to create multimedia component using web 8 Core service of Tridion. But for non-admin users, there is an error as:

> The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.

This error occurs at UploadBinaryContent method call:

```
//streamclient is an object of StreamUploadClient class
AccessTokenData accessToken = client.GetCurrentUser();
if (accessToken.ExpiresAt <= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2))
{
  objfilestream = new FileStream(extractToFolder.ToString() + "\\" + fileToUpload.Name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
  Stream stream = objfilestream;
  string filepath = streamClient.UploadBinaryContent(accessToken, stream);
}
```

Please can you help with this issue, so that non-admin users can also create multimedia components using web 8 core service.

Comment: Have you checked the publication and folder level permission for non-admin users? If they don't have component management permission at publication level or if they don't have write permission at folder level then the creation can fail.

Comment: As Hiren says, this may be a security issue for the non-admin user. Can you try logging-in to the CME interface as that user (on one with the same permissions) and creating one manually in the same folder?

Answer (score 2):

Increase buffer size limit in TcmServiceHost.exe.config, you need to add a maxBufferSize parameter (it is set to 500KB here):

```
<binding name="StreamUpload_netTcpBinding" maxBufferSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="StreamedRequest" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" />
```